# JQuery parse XML data slower

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am parsing an XML in jquery which has alot of data. When it starts after a few seconds it crashes my page. Is there a way I can add a timer or some sort of way to slow the parsing down, or slow how many pieces of data are being parsed per second?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `setInterval(function, millis)` function.
This function executes your desired code once every n milliseconds.

For example, to print "HELLO" every second, I would write...

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("HELLO");
}, 1000);
```

You could use this to bite off chunks of data from your dataset.

Alternatively, if you are requesting your data from an API, try and look for a means of paginating your data so that the API returns it in smaller chunks for you.